# when does U.S. Patent No. 7930340 expire?

Tags: expire

When does [7930340](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7930340B2/en) expire?  PTA days are  577;  filed 5/23/2001;  issued  4/19/2011;  last RCE  filed 6/30/2009.

Comment: Could you link the patent document?  It looks like, if it were granted, it would expire in 2021...

Comment: Pair shows the 371(c) date as 05-23-2001. However, it also seems to claim priority to a provisional filed 11-13-1995. "This application is a continuation in part of application Ser. No. 09/792,323 filed Feb. 23, 2001, now U.S. Pat. No. 7,340,506, which was a continuation-in-part of application Ser. No. 08/879,958 filed Jun. 20, 1997, now U.S. Pat. No. 5,987,500 which was a divisional of application Ser. No. 08/700,726 filed Aug. 5, 1996, now U.S. Pat. No. 5,778,178 which was related to and claimed priority from U.S. provisional patent application No. 60/006,634 filed Nov. 13, 1995."

Comment: The fact that there are so many continuation-in-parts is why this is more interesting then other questions of this type.

Answer (score 2):

If field (22) is 2001, and it is not a continuation from a previous patent, than add 20 years + 551 days to 2001 and you have your date.